# generate onclick event in image control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

i am have one datalist in asp.net

i m using vb with asp

now my code is just as follow

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
```

```
<tr>

    <br />

   <td>

   Question Number:

        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question_no") %>' />

        <br />

   Cust_id:

        <asp:Label ID="Cust_idLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Cust_id") %>' />

        <br />

        Question:

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>' />

        <br />

        Time:

        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date_time") %>' />

        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ImagesFolde/Chrysanthemum.jpg" Height="50" Width="50" **OnClientClick="s()"**/>
```

all this in datalist as you can see

**so it will be repeated..**

i have put one image in it

now i want call a method when any image will be clicked

i make one sub called **s() in vb**

i want to call it

i use on **clientclick() event** but doesn't work

what to do?

Comment: Are there any console errors? Where is `s` defined?

Comment: s is defined in my back in vb language

Comment: Then there's your problem, you're using what expects client-side code, but your code is server-side.

Comment: what i have to do any suggestion?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between the client and the server.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:ImageButton  ID="imgexpand" runat="server" ImageAlign="Bottom" ImageUrl="~/img/plus.png" OnClick="s" />
```

you do not need the `()` in the control onclick statement 
this will fire the `sub s()` procedure in the vb code

Answer (score 0):

you use onclientclick - have you made your functions with javascript/jquery ? ( the server side won't be fired)

for instance :
if you call you client method like this :

```
OnClientClick="return myFunction();"
```

then your function should be in the header as follows:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
   function myFunction()
   {
       alert("activated here");
   }
</script>
```

Comment: can i call my vb script from javascript. i m using vb as behind in asp

Comment: no - why would you want to do that ? unless on click - you want to get data from DB you can do every event using javascript ( and it's also go much faster ).

Comment: asp:image doesn't have onclick or onclientclick event.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a datalist:

ASPX:

```
<asp:DataList id="ItemsList" OnItemCommand="Item_Command" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton id="SelectButton" Text="Select" CommandName="ModifyRow" 
      runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id")%>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:DataList>
```

VB (Code  Behind) :
Here I am taking the id from `'<%#Eval("Id")%>'` and binding some products in bulleted list:

```
Protected Sub ItemsList_ItemCommand _
    (source As Object, e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs) _
    Handles Categories.ItemCommand
    If e.CommandName = "ModifyRow" Then
        ' Determine the CategoryID
        Dim categoryID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        ' Get the associated products from the ProudctsBLL and
        ' bind them to the BulletedList
        Dim products As BulletedList = _
            CType(e.Item.FindControl("ProductsInCategory"), BulletedList)
        Dim productsAPI As New ProductsBLL()
        products.DataSource = productsAPI.GetProductsByCategoryID(categoryID)
        products.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for help but but what do u mean by Categories here what i has to write there

Comment: i have name the onitemcommand with as "aa" .now i got error like       : 'aa' is not a member of 'ASP.default9_aspx'.